# How do I save state between app launched using UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display, using a `UILabel`, the time/date (Date or NSDate), formatted using a `DateFormatter` of each previous app launch when I start the app.

So, every time I launch the app there should be another date that is displayed on the screen.

For example, if this is the first time launching, it will display `Nov 18 2018, 13:15`. And the second launch it should display

```
Nov 18 2018, 13:15 
Nov 18 2018, 13:16
```

The third launch it should display something like

```
 Nov 18 2018, 13:15 
 Nov 18 2018, 13:16
 Nov 18 2018, 13:17
```

Currently, my code only displays the time of the launch but does not record previous launches. If anyone can give me some directions on how to use `UserDefaults` to achieve this I will really appreciate it!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Timelabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"

        let DisplayTime: Date = Date()
        print(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: DisplayTime))
        Timelabel.text = "Current Time: \(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: DisplayTime))"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as following

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // your other @IBOutlet / properties
    let ARR_KEY = "launch_time"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // your other code.
        // remove your TimeLabel.text = ... line

        let formattedDateTime = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: DisplayTime)


        // storing the launch date time
        if var arr = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: ARR_KEY){
            arr.append(formattedDateTime)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(arr, forKey: ARR_KEY)
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set([formattedDateTime], forKey: ARR_KEY)       
        }

        displayLaunchTimeInSimpleLabel()
    }

    func displayLaunchTimeInSimpleLabel() {
        if var arr = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: ARR_KEY){
               var string = ""
               for launchTime in arr {
                   string = string + launchTime + "\n"
               }
               Timelabel.text = string
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it legal to append to arr? Isn't it a constant since you used let?

Comment: It still only displays the current time. Do I have to connect the UILabel to something?

Comment: Don't suggest `value(forKey` unless you can explain why KVC is mandatory. There is `array(forKey`

Comment: do you want to listing all the app launch time ?

Comment: @RatulSharker Yeah I want to display all the previous launch time and the current one.

Comment: To display all the launch times, you may want to look into `UITableView` instead of simple `UILabel`. You just could show it for demo purpose, but to scroll down like features, you need `UITableView`

Comment: It is required that we use UILabel, but I am wondering how do I print out the saved dates in this code?

Comment: According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize) the synchronize is `unnecessary and shouldn't be used`.

Comment: @CharlieFish I have updated code according to your suggestion, I also read the doc, the doc says **this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used** and the method isn't deprecated yet,  but there is no explanation behind this. Would you mind reasoning if there is any explanation of downside calling this `synchronize()` method ?

Comment: @RatulSharker From what I'm aware of, there is no downside of calling the `synchronize` method, other than it is unnecessary, which even if it's just for clean code sake, I don't think you should use. I'm unaware of the technical implications of it tho. I'm assuming calling the `synchronize` method must have some type of performance implication. Like even if Apple's implementation of the method does absolutely nothing (which is probably unlikely), I still think that would have some type of performance implication. It might be SUPER minor tho.